# No. of ways of factorizing a number into three distinct factors

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

> Question: Let m be the number of triplets (p,q,r) of positive integer such that
> p<q<r and pqr is the square of the product of primes between 2 to 19
> (including), when m is divided by 100 what would be the remainder.

This is my work:[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: [Are you saying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) $pqr=19\#^2$?

Comment: How many ways are there of distributing 16 balls, numbered 1 to 8 with two balls for each number, among 3 buckets so that no two buckets have balls with the exact same numbers in them? How many ways are there to arrange 3 distinct buckets?

Comment: Do you have the answer to this question, i want to verify if my answer is correct in which case i can post it

Comment: I don't have the answer, but the options given are: (a)28, (b)88, (c)8, (d)48